# getBoundingClientRect returning an incorrect results when changing routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, getboundingclientrect

I'm using this hook in order to get the offset from the top of the page to the top of an element. It seemed to work fine until I started navigating through my react-router page routes.

```
const usePosition = () => {
    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth,
    });
    const [offsets, setOffsets] = useState({
        offsetTop: 0,
        offsetBottom: 0,
    });
    const ref = useRef();

    const handleResize = () => {
        setDimensions({
            height: window.innerHeight,
            width: window.innerWidth,
        });
    };

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const position = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        setOffsets({
            offsetTop: window.pageYOffset + position.top,
            offsetBottom: window.pageYOffset + position.bottom,
        });

        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, [ref, dimensions, setOffsets]);

    return [ref, offsets, dimensions];
};

export default usePosition;
```

Upon loading the website this ImagesBanner element would work fine but when I would leave and then go back to the route with my ImagesBanner, getBoundingClientRect(); returns an incorrect top and bottom value, therefore, throwing off the animation.

```
const ImagesBanner = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    const [ref, offsets, dimensions] = usePosition();
    const { scrollY } = useViewportScroll();

    const fetchImages = async () => {
        const images = await getClientImages();
        setImages(images);
    };

    const transformX = useTransform(
        scrollY,
        [offsets.offsetTop - dimensions.height, offsets.offsetBottom],
        [
            (images.length * 450 - 200) * -1 + dimensions.width / 2,
            images.length * 450 - 200 - dimensions.width / 2,
        ]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchImages();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="images-banner">
            <div className="images-banner__title">
                <h2 className="heading">Our Clients</h2>
            </div>
            <motion.div
                className="images-banner__slider"
                ref={ref}
                style={{ left: transformX }}
            >
                {images.map((image) => (
                    <div key={image.node.id} className="images-banner__slide">
                        <img
                            src={image.node.logo.url}
                            alt={image.node.client}
                        />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </motion.div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ImagesBanner;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey I'm dealing with the same problem right now, did you ever figure out why this was happening? Thanks!